# Binary Search Tree in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I am trying to implement a BST in Solidity 0.8.12 using the address as indexer.

So, after creating a Node contract using

```
contract Node{
    Node public __left; // TODO : create helpers
    Node public __right;  // TODO : create helpers

    function getAddress() public view returns (address){return address(this);}
    function getLeft() public view returns (Node){return __left;}
    function getRight() public view returns (Node){return __right;}
    function setLeft(Node _curr) public {__left = _curr;}
    function setRight(Node _curr) public {__right = _curr;}

    function isNull() public view returns (bool){
        if (address(this) == address(0)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

I created a contract NodeBST with two add() approaches. The first one was a recursive attempt, which would potentially lead me into infinite gas, but I still wanted to check it out.

```
contract NodeBST is Node{

    function add(Node _newNode) public returns (Node){
        if (address(this) < _newNode.getAddress()){
            __left = add(_newNode);
        }
        else if (address(this) > _newNode.getAddress()){
            __right = add(_newNode);
        }
        else{
            return _newNode;
        }
        return _newNode;
    }
(...)
```

and despite of the potential gas issue, my Remix got out of memory when I tried to include a new Node (I deployed 3 instances of the Node contract and an instance of NodeBST and run add() and so on).

Would someone know how to fix it? (so fixing the memory leak?)

So I tried an interactive method,

```
function add_iter(Node _newNode) public payable {
    Node current = this; // Starts the root as the proper node

    while(true){ //address(current)!=address(0)
        if (_newNode < current){
            if (!current.getLeft().isNull()){
                current = __left;
            }
            else{
                current.setLeft(_newNode);
                break;
            }
        } 
        else if (_newNode >= current){
            if (!current.getRight().isNull()){
                current = __right;
            }
            else{
                current.setRight(_newNode);
                break;
            }
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

which returned me the following error

> transact to NodeBST.add_iter pending ... transact to NodeBST.add_iter errored: VM error: revert.
>
> revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.
>
> [vm]from: 0x5B3...eddC4to: NodeBST.add_iter(address) 0xd8b...33fa8value: 30000 weidata: 0x949...39138logs: 0hash: 0x700...cfbc8 status false Transaction mined but execution failed transaction hash 0x700cab2cb8022734c84e9aa7e7112a9f6bf3c84d8887324bff41f92a61fcfbc8 from 0x5B38Da6a701c568545dCfcB03FcB875f56beddC4 to NodeBST.add_iter(address) 0xd8b934580fcE35a11B58C6D73aDeE468a2833fa8 gas 80000000 gas transaction cost 28229 gas execution cost 28229 gas input 0x949...39138 decoded input { "address _newNode": "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138" } decoded output {} logs [] val 30000 wei

What did I miss here? Or... would someone have another idea to implement a BST?

Thanks!